# Hard coding the query in database expert for crystal report( while multiple values needed for parameters)

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Due to the complexity of the report ,am feeding sql query in Database expert(Creating a command).Here for a parameter field 'status' which can have multiple values which way I should prepare the query? I am a rookie in crystal reporting,and any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks!

if parameter contains only one values I am giving it this way :
where wrk_status={?dynastatus} ;

Now for multiple input how should I modify the query? 
I tried wrk_status IN ('{?dynastatus}') ,but it throwing error.

Comment: @Siva
Here is the command below:
select * from wis.ym_work_item_plan wip where wip.status_cd in ('{?Status}') and wip.date_record_created_ts >={?startdate} and wip.date_record_created_ts  <={?enddate}with ur;

it gets results when I don't check 'Allow Multiple values' in Status Command Parameter.(User can choose only one among 'STR','PEND','NEW')

Comment: But while ticking the the check box:Error appearing in a dialog box as per below.
Failed to retrive data from databse.
Details:42601:[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/linuxx8664] SQL0104n an unexpected token 'STR','PND','NEW' was found following "ip.status_cd in('('".Expected tokens 

may include: "<space>". SQLSTATE=42601
[Database Vendor Code:-104]

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `wrk_status = {?dynastatus}`. If your parameter is set to allow multiple values then you don't have to change the select statement. 
If you specify distinct values for your parameter, the syntax would be `wrk_status IN [value1, value2, value3, etc]`

Comment: Not sure why,but that didn't work for me,I am not in my workspace and I don't remember the exact error is.Will keep you posted .Thanks!

Comment: wrk_status IN ('{?dynastatus}') worked for me when there is only one value,but didnt work well as expected on multiple value selections.

Comment: :Error appearing in a dialog box as per below. Failed to retrive data from databse. Details:42601:[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/linuxx8664] SQL0104n an unexpected token 'STR','PND','NEW' was found following "ip.status_cd in('('".Expected tokens may include: "<space>". SQLSTATE=42601 [Database Vendor Code:-104
Above is the error I am getting. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try 
wrk_status IN {?dynastatus}

Comment: That didn't work for me..It showing error while multiple values are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a parameter in command there is option `Allow Multiple Values` use that.

Comment: I know I can use that and I did it,But Command query(Select query ) underlying throwing error :(

Comment: @JijilKakkadathu If possible paste the query here... lets see if something is wrong or something can be done to it

Comment: Here is the command below: select * from wis.ym_work_item_plan wip where wip.status_cd in ('{?Status}') and wip.date_record_created_ts >={?startdate} and wip.date_record_created_ts <={?enddate}with ur; it gets results when I don't check 'Allow Multiple values' in Status Command Parameter.(User can choose only one among 'STR','PEND','NEW')

Comment: Try the query by removing `with ur`.

Comment: 'ur'for uncommited read ,Tried removing 'with ur' ,but no luck